# Java program custom exception generates a compile error

Tags: java

I am trying to create a custom exception in Java, however, I get a compile error when I create the custom exception and try to use it. I have searched through this forum and did not provide much help, because I try to use similar code and it still does not fix the problem!

Here's the code:

```
class CoogieException extends Exception {
  public int numCats;
  public String msg;

  public CoogieException() {

  }

  public CoogieException(String msg) {
       super();
       this.msg = msg;
  }

  public int getNumCats() {
       return numCats;
  }

}
```

and the main class -

```
public class Lab12 {

 public int checkValue(int numCats) throws CoogieException {
     if (numCats != (int) numCats) {
         throw new CoogieException("Sorry, invalid entry");
     } else {
         return numCats;
     }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {

     CoogieException test = new CoogieException(); 
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter num of cats: ");
    int numCats = in.nextInt();
    try {
        lb = new Lab12();
        lb.checkValue(numCats);
    } catch (CoogieException co) {
        System.out.println("numCats is too many cats!!!!!");
    }

 }
}
```

FYI...

```
  Lab12.java:27: error: incompatible types: CoogieException cannot be     converted to Throwable
  public int checkValue(int numCats) throws CoogieException {
                                           ^
   Lab12.java:29: error: incompatible types: CoogieException cannot be converted to Throwable
         throw new CoogieException("Sorry, invalid entry");
         ^
  Lab12.java:119: error: incompatible types: CoogieException cannot be converted to Throwable
    } catch (CoogieException co) {
```

Comment: `"however, I get a compile error when I create the custom exception"` -- then wouldn't it be wise to post the complete compiler error with your question?

Comment: Note that this: `public CoogieException(String msg) {  super();  this.msg = msg; }` should be changed to: `public CoogieException(String msg) { super(msg);  }

Comment: included compile error.

Comment: What do you think `numCats != (int) numCats` is going to do?

Comment: I did that, and got: "error: constructor Exception in class Exception cannot be applied to given types;"

Comment: Seems to compile alright for me, I be making sure you don't have a custom class called `Exception` or another class in a different package called `CoogieException` which doesn't extend from `Exception`

Comment: I use numCats != (int) numCats to check if it's integer or not. not sure if that could be the reason.

Comment: FYI, Java is a [strongly typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing) language. `int` can only be an integer. If someone enters a non-integer, [in.nextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) will throw some exception. That said, this is not the cause of your error.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have a class somewhere called `Exception` that doesn't extend `java.lang.Exception` (or implement `Throwable`). Also possible you have another class called `CoogieException` with the same problem.